Why no ellipses in this sentence: X have both beneficial and detrimental effects on Y and on Z

In conclusion, this increase will have both beneficial and detrimental effects on individuals and on the economy.

In a writing sample answer written by a native speaker, he used on twice in a row as seen above. If this had been written by a non-native speaker, I wouldn't have considered it good writing since I see no justifiable reason why they didn't remove the second on.
However, this is a native speaker's work, so maybe there's a good unexpected reason behind it. Is there?

For clarity and emphasis. It's a style.

The repetition of on presents individuals and the economy as separate things, as distinct from a coordinated relationship:

... effects on individuals and on the economy.
... effects on individuals and the economy.

Each affected thing appears in its own prepositional phrase in the first.  The second could be understood to refer to some interplay or relationship between individuals and the economy.
Compare:

I spoke to Tom and to Jerry.
I spoke to Tom and Jerry.

Repeating the preposition for each can help to make clear that they were spoken to separately. It's not that the coordinated version cannot be intended  to have that meaning in context, but it is a suboptimal way of expressing that meaning because the coordination suggests otherwise.

Another, very similar example: I wrote to Aunt Mary and (to) Uncle Peter. Without the to it sounds as thought a single letter was sent to the two of them. With the to it sounds as though each relative received separate letter.
